# Como importar meus estilos CSS e meus scripts JS para um projeto do ângular?

Tags: javascript, front-end, typescript, angular

Tenho um projeto em Angular 2, e gostaria de importar os scripts e folhas de estilos para o meu projeto.

Quando eu vou encapsular meu projeto em sessões, o ângular não interpreta de forma adequada os arquivos para a estilização de todo o projeto.

Minha estrutura esta da seguinte forma:

[image: Estrutura do meu projeto Angular]

Gostaria obter os meus arquivos para dentro dos meus componentes Angular. Pois eles não estão emulando da forma adequada.

```
Obs: Eu já importei no meu index todos os meus arquivos necessários. Tanto na <header>, e também antes da tag body.

<!doctype html>
<html lang="pt-br">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <base href="/">

  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>TITLE</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/lib/css/ARQUIVO.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/lib/rateyo/css/ARQUIVO.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/lib/css/ARQUIVO.min.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/lib/css/ARQUIVO.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/lib/css/ARQUIVO.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/lib/css/ARQUIVO.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/style.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/responsive.css" />
  <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/lib/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/lib/rateyo/js/jquery.rateyo.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/rating.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

      <app-root></app-root>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/loading.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/lib/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/lib/js/material.min.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/lib/js/uikit.min.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/lib/js/sticky.min.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/lib/js/flip.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/lib/js/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/script.js"></script>

    </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Acredito que você tenha gerado seu projeto usando o `angular-cli`, `ng new`.

Se for esse o caso, basta você ir no seu arquivo `.angular-cli.json`, nas sessôes `styles` e `scripts` e informar um array com todos os arquivos `.css` e `.js` que deseja importar.

Assim no build de sua aplicação esses arquivos serão inseridos no seu projeto (no bundle de `vendors` se não me engano). Sei que a documentação do `angular-cli` não é uma das melhores, mas de uma olhada na sessão sobre o `.angular-cli.json`: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/angular-cli

### Exemplo:

```
...
  "styles": [
    "assets/css/style.css"
  ],
  "scripts": [
    "assets/js/script.js"
  ]
...
```

**Atenção**, ao adicionar esses arquivos por meio do `.angular-cli.json` o build vai passar eles pelos `loaders` do `webpack`, assim podem aparecer alguns `warnings` na sua aplicação pois os `loaders` algumas vezes dão dicas de atributos depreciados de css ou algumas outras dicas.

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta! Mas dessa forma não consegui gerar os resultados. Eu fiz de outra forma, declarando explicitamente mesmo lá no HTML5... mas devo mudar em breve!